# How to handle Duplicate users or user profiles?

Tags: discussion, support

When I'm going through posted questions. I saw two questions of a different profiles, I felt like both profiles of a single user

### Questions:

- [How to run a Sdl Tridion develop WebSite on localhost](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/how-to-run-a-sdl-tridion-develop-website-on-localhost)
- [How to create a WebSite on Sdl Tridion using core service.please write the step.](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/how-to-create-a-website-on-sdl-tridion-using-core-service-please-write-the-step)

### User Profiles:

- [Pankaj Sharma](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/924/pankaj-sharma)
- [pankaj](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/907/pankaj)

> **How to handle this case?**

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want/need to handle there?

Does it really matter who asked a question, as long as the question is a good fit on the site and it is clear, you can upvote it, else don't or consider downvoting it (but I do always suggest you leave a comment on why you think it deserved a downvote). I don't think you should even consider looking as who really asked it, that is rather irrelevant I would say.

With regards to duplicate questions, if you feel a question is a duplicate of another (again, irrelevant if they were posted by the same or a different user), just flag it as a duplicate. If others agree, it will be closed as a duplicate (requires 5 user votes or a single moderator vote).

Comment: For duplicate question, we can flag it has duplicate that's the ideally behaviour. But in case of duplicate user, user can misuse this. Example: User can post the question with first profile and with other duplicate user profile, user can give upvote him/her self. So that's my concern and how we can handle it.

Comment: This is the initial state, where we can take some decision.

Comment: @SivaCharan if you feel there is a concern of users using sock puppet accounts to upvote themselves, just flag anything of them for moderator attention and state your suspicion. As a moderator we have tools to identify if certain users possibly are the same and if they are abusing the system. But generally you needn't worry about that too much being a regular user, if it is happening on a huge scale, chances are the moderators already have this on their radar.
There are currently 3 users with the name Pankaj, but we have 9 with the name John, I think we shouldn't look too much at the name ;)

Comment: Ok, will do that way. Thanks for the information.

Comment: It's definitely a balance between good behavior, honor, and the nice tools StackExchange provides moderators. Complete transparency may not be a requirement as I'd imagine there are some questions you might not want to ask *publicly* (mainly due to embarrassment that you should know everything). As a warning on the other side--a username change apparently has a 30-day minimum wait time. Probably best to avoid picking a "temporary" name. :-)